# Wordpress - Moved to CENTOS server now links dont work

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have just transferred an exiting WordPress site with WooCommerce onto a new CentOS server.

I created a virtual host, which looks like the one below:

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/website/public_html"
        <Directory "/var/www/website/public_html">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                 # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
                 AllowOverride All
                # Controls who can get stuff from this server file
                 Order allow,deny
                 Allow from all
       </Directory>
        <IfModule mpm_peruser_module>
                ServerEnvironment apache apache
        </IfModule>
        ErrorLog  /var/www/website.co.uk/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/website.co.uk/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I then installed all the files and imported the database.

The issue is that whenever I visit any other page other than the homepage, using the "Post name" permalink I get a 404 error. For example, vising `/shop` gives a 404 error, however I can access the shop page via `/?p=4` when using the plain, this just creates the following `.htaccess` file:

```bash
# BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
```

But, whenever I do something such as post names the following get's entered:

```bash
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`mod_rewrite.c` is enabled as I found it in my `phpinfo()` contents.

Any ideas to where I am going wrong?

**Edit:** If I do something like:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
asfl;asjflasfj
```

It shows as an Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you checked the log files?

Comment: @CBroe Please see update

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Go to wordpress admin area http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/, login as admin.
2. Go to Settings -> Permalinks and click on "Save Changes" button.

Now go to home page of your site and refresh page and visit other links to see if they are working.

Comment: Please make sure that .htaccess in the root of WordPress has write access.

Comment: It does - For example, if I changed something in the Permalinks then it updates the .htaccess file